# How to secure a compromised computer while getting proof against the attacker

Tags: windows

I have evidence (non-technical) that my company is spying on me, not on my company PC but my private PC at home.
These evidences won’t hold in court, so I am in need of technical proof. I suspect that my company has hired a hacker to monitor my PC, 
but I need technical evidence to prove that. And I need to find a way to block them out. Please don't ask about motivation etc. I will go into the details about the non technical side of this.

I know that this platform is very strict about “vague” questions, but I am desperate for a solution and this is the best platform I know of for
security experts. So please don’t cut this question.

My Home PC:
- Windows7 Premium with latest security updates.

- Firewall on with modified default settings: inbound traffic is blocked except for windows services (remote access has been disabled). Outbound Traffic is set allow windows services, Email Client (Claws Mail), latest Opera-Browser and the gaming platform Steam
- Antivirus: Avira Community Edition
- Malware Detection: Spybot search & destroy
- IPV6 has been disabled

I use my company passwords also for private services (windows logon, private email), but I changed that as of late.
Now I am using lastpass with a new strong master password.

My Company-Phone (iPhone4) was granted access to my private WLAN, but I had its access removed and now I am using a private Nexus 7 tablet instead.
I have to logon to company servers from home in order to access work related documents and mails (part of my work), so they can see my IP quite often.

What I need to know now are two things:

- How can I further secure my home setup (installing Linux is not an option because I am depended on windows software. And yes I tried wine)
- How can I catch the hacker “in the act” so that I have strong proof?

Comment: The most likely infection vector is probably email in this case. Do you read your company emails at home on your home PC? Also it would help if you could describe what leads you to believe that they have compromised your PC. Odd behaviour? Knowledge of things they can only know by reading your home email?

Comment: How do you connect to your company servers from home, via VPN ? Do you have any company specific application installed on your system ?

Comment: Yes, i do read my company-email from my HomePC. I also use the company accounting software from home. They are both webbased and commercial versions of open source software. My Browser ist Opera enhanced with Adblock, Https Anywhere, Ghostley, Disconnect, WOT and so on. I am not connected via VPN.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't go deep into the "how do you know" (they read stack* sites as well), but they know very private things which are impossible to know without monitoring my browser habits **and** reading my private email (GMail).

Comment: 1. As long as you are using the company network, they probably have broad latitude in what they can do to "protect it".  2. If there is snooping going on, it's possible that it isn't authorized or part of the company's policy, just a rogue employee.  You could broach the question with the top IT person or a company officer to find out whether such activity is authorized.  If it isn't, they might initiate their own investigation.  You don't have to tip your hand about your planned actions.  3. If you go to court, you may have to show damages, which is hard, and kiss your job goodbye.

Answer (score 2):

This question is in fact two questions.

To respond to this security incident, you would have to collect an usable proof, then secure the computer.

Having a proof which you can use in court can be difficult. In fact, should you defend your case against a judge (or your company chiefs), they will likely try to show that:

- you can't prove the information is genuine, and you did not forge it.
- the "intrusions" are within the boundaries of the eventual security policy of the firm (which you should have seen and signed btw.) It's a way to say that you accepted these.

The way to go, would be to have an accredited person (expert lawyer??) conducting an audit on your computer then releasing a legal report that could be used in court. For this, you'll have to keep doing things as usual to allow for data collection. A *post-mortem* audit could also be performed, but it's more than likely this won't give any usable results mostly due to the fact the computer is yours and you have full access to it.

So if you want to have any proof, you need to seek for a legal counselor, who can advise you on what to do. But I'm pretty sure the investment is not worth the harm.

On the securing part of the question: trusting a known compromised computer is not really easy. Unless you can assess the full restoration of all the files on the computer (verifying that your system is genuine - and the tool you checked this is as well), you won't ever be sure that there are no trace of backdoors or malware infection. So the next best thing is complete wipe and reinstallation of the operating system. Do you installation offline, then path online with the lastest updates. Then you will need to take contraptions to avoid corrupting the system again.

To protect yourself, you must first ask you this question: "Who do I trust". If you do not trust your company, then why would you install their software, access their servers? I will there assume you need to set up a VPN access to be able to use the tools you need to work. Using a VPN is basically saying "I do trust this network I'm connecting to". You can think of it as an extension of your own home network. If you do not trust what is on that network, you need to isolate your environment.

You have some solutions that differ mostly by their convenience and/or price. You can:

- Get a new PC solely used for work purposes.
- Set up a virtual environment with virtual machines programs (Virtualbox, etc...)
- Set up a second environment on a second disk on your computer.

Whichever you chose, you have to ensure isolation of your computer. More precisely you should make sure that:

- other computers on your network cannot be reached from your secured environment (network filtering, access rules)
- other data on your computer cannot be accessed from you secured environment (disconnected HDD for ex.)

So, basically, don't give access to what you don't want to share.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You are right, i have to setup a new PC and isolate it from the rest. I am afraid that they will get suspicious and stop monitoring me. In this case i will never be able to proof it in a legal case. I already had everthing i singed handed to a lawyer and he mentioned nothing about a clause in any of my contracts & policies which would legalize what they did. You are also right about the proofing part. It's impossible to find a lawyer who can do such an audit & proof that i did not forge it. I'll have to find precedents to see how these cases are handled.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is compromised, you can't trust it.  It could be lying to you.  Therefore, you need to be able to gather evidence from a system you do trust.  Such as a transparent router running in promiscuous mode.  The most tell-tale proof would probably be a packet capture.  Logs can be useful; timestamping them would be good.

If you do get some clear-cut evidence, prepare to kiss your computer(s) good bye.  There will probably be plenty of opportunity for you to tamper with evidence, which is a fact that doesn't work out in your favor.  One thing that may help to minimize your ability to tamper with a crime scene is for law enforcement to "tag it and bag it"...  transport your computer to a computer forensics lab where they take weeks to find out anything.

If this is beyond your area of expertise, you may want to get someone else to help.  In fact, getting an unbiased person might help your case.  However, this may also be an expense.

All of this may be assuming that the attacker is less clever than your attempts to catch (meaning: record) the attacker's actions.  If all you do is capture packets and create logs, but they don't show any signs of attack, then you've accomplished nothing beneficial to yourself (even if the attacks are, in fact, actually happening).  For instance, doing crazy awesome things with a firewall might not help you at all if the attack is not happening via a network.

If you can manage to do this (have the technical expertise, and equipment, or sufficient funds to afford such equipment), making a drive image now may be helpful later.  The drive image may help to show just what has changed.  But, if they've already installed monitoring software, then even your first image may be infected, which limits the usefulness of this approach.

One thing that you don't want is for your Microsoft Windows machine to be joined to the Active Directory domain, if you're trying to keep them out.  A lot of people don't understand this; joining an Active Directory domain may help you to access company resources.  It also gives them a lot of control over the computer.

If they are "spying" on you by using a cracked firewall to see what websites you go to, then nothing you do on your computer will help.  You could replace your whole computer, and the malicious firewall device would still be able to spy on the new computer.  If the problem is that they got into your home and replaced your keyboard with one that logs your keystrokes, and uses a built-in antenna to transmit your keystrokes outside of your house, then replacing your firewall will accomplish nothing.  (And, wiping your hard drive and re-installing your operating system, while you still use your keyboard, will accomplish nothing.)  If they are spying on you by using a camera they hid in your office at home, replacing all of your computer technology could accomplish... nothing.  The right way to successfully defend against their attack will depend on just what they do.

Lots of suggestions can be given; some might help, many might not.  Since the number of ways that an attack could occur is approximately sixteen multiplied by infinity, there's no clear course of action that I can recommend that will guarantee success; especially when the details you provide are so vague.